# exec or ajax? PHP background script

Tags: php, ajax, exec, shell-exec

I have a script which i need to run as soon as a user logs in to my system..

So, they log in, all checks done, I want to fire a background script to process some other stuff while starting their session and sending them away using header().

The flow is:

User log in

user info checks

load background script with variable

start session, then header()

I'm trying:

```
 shell_exec("/usr/bin/php /pages/test/backg.php {$user} &");
```

But nothing is happening with it (I'm testing result by putting simple email to me at start of script so i know if its even fired)

Is there a better way to do this, using ajax? Can ajax accept variables and how is it done? Is it more effcicient than this way (when this works I mean!)

Comment: I doubt you have a *root level* directory called `/pages`. Additionally, you might want to use [`exec`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) instead and check the output, or even [`proc_open`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) for even more control over the execution environment.

Comment: In addition to the checks suggested by DCoder, did you check if your php script works? Did you launch it from a shell?

Comment: Guys thank you - script fine but @DCoder correct, wrong bloody path!